# Bind Drop Down List to SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am struggling to bind a Drop Down List to a Data Source.  Please see the code below:

```
Private _ConString As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        _ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString
        SqlDataSourceNicheDuplicates.ConnectionString = _ConString
        SqlDataSourceCreatedDate.ConnectionString = _ConString
        SqlDataSourceCreatedDate.SelectCommand = "SELECT dateadded distinct convert(varchar,dateadded,103) as dateadded dbNicheDuplicates"
        DDLCreatedDate.DataTextField = "dateadded"
        DDLCreatedDate.DataValueField = "dateadded"
        DDLCreatedDate.DataBind()
end sub
```

If I run the SQL statement in SQL Studio Manager then many results are returned.  What am I doing wrong?

I have spent some time Googling this.  For example I looked at this question: [Populating an ASP.Net DropDownList using VB.Net coding in code-behind file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710292/populating-an-asp-net-dropdownlist-using-vb-net-coding-in-code-behind-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding more info to [lincolnk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144542/lincolnk) answer. You need to do this - `DDLCreatedDate.DataSource = SqlDataSourceCreatedDate;`

```
SqlDataSourceCreatedDate.SelectCommand = "SELECT dateadded distinct convert(varchar,dateadded,103) as dateadded dbNicheDuplicates"
DDLCreatedDate.DataSource = SqlDataSourceCreatedDate;
DDLCreatedDate.DataTextField = "dateadded"
DDLCreatedDate.DataValueField = "dateadded"
DDLCreatedDate.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the drop down list is still empty.

Comment: @w0051977, are you sure this SQL `SELECT dateadded distinct convert(varchar,dateadded,103) as dateadded dbNicheDuplicates` is working in management console?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  There were two tables: dbNicheDuplicates and dbo.dbNicheDuplicate.  dbo.dbNicheDuplicate had no data.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `DataSource`.

```
DDLCreatedDate.DataSource = <results>
DDLCreatedDate.DataBind()
```

You don't list what type of objects your working with so I'm not sure exactly what the missing statement is.